# Can you help me write the perfect ORM query for django with postgres for the following criteria?

Tags: postgresql, django-orm

So I have a model like this,

```
    class AlphabetArray(models.Model):
        slug = ArrayField(
                        models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True),
                        null=True,default=list)
```

And in the field `slug` we might have values like `['a','b','c',.....'z']` Is it possible to query this model such that, 
I get the objects with slugs only containing atleast one, or both of a list of `['d','e']` but not any other alphabet?

So I am querying for objects with either `'d'`, `'e'`, or both `'d'` and `'e'` but not any other alphabets?

Comment: So I know ```overlap``` exists but that is not what I am looking for, its the straight opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer to this question,

`alphabets = AlphabetArray.objects.filter( Q ( slug__contained_by=['d','e'] ) | Q ( slug__len__gte=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for 2 overlaps:

1. The target array does overlap array['d','e']
2. The target array does **not** overlap array['a','b','c','f' ... 'z']

The following accomplishes in SQL, since I don't django you will have to adapt it.  You won't need the CTE nor the select_it in final, but they are useful for testing.

```
-- setup test cases
with test_array_sets (test_array,select_it) as 
   ( values (array['d','e'],'Yes') 
          , (array['d','e','f'],'No')
          , (array[]::text[],'No')
          , (array['x','y','z'],'No')
          , (array['d'],'Yes')
          , (array['e'],'Yes')
    )
-- actual query needed,  
select target_array, select_it
  from test_array_sets
 where not target_array && array['a','b','c','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 
   and target_array && array['d','e'] ;
```